# AJax Sucess function doesnot work on safari browser

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, safari

I have a ajax function like this

```
    $.ajax({
  url: "thankyou",
  type: "POST", 
  data: arr,
  tryCount : 0,
  retryLimit : 3,
  success: function(response) {
    if(response == "Success"){
    location.href = "/thankyou.html";
   }else{console.log(response);}
  },
  error: function(xhr,textStatus) {
    if (textStatus == 'timeout') {
            this.tryCount++;
            if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                //try again
                $.ajax(this);
                return;
            }            
            return;
        }

  }
});
```

There is also my Nodejs express app which sends the response correclty. It works perfectly in chrome and Im able to go to the thankyou.html page after successfull response. But my page doesn't navigate to thankyou.html in safari browser . I'm using safari 10.0.1 . The same doesn't work in my Iphone or Ipad safari browser as well. Kindly help . Thank you for the answer in advance

Comment: is this a typo  if(response = "Success"){ ?? you need to have ==

Comment: Try changing location.href to: window.location.href.

If that don't work, try using window.location .

One of them should work in Safari.

Comment: @karthikGanesan . Sorry fixed the typo now

Comment: @korgrue : It still doesn't work

Comment: One other thing to try. I have had double equal comparisons not work in Safari when testing against a string for some reason.  Change (response == "Success") to (response === "Success") and see if that works.

Also try putting an alert inside of the closure to see if the client is even getting past the evaluation.

Comment: @Korgrue I changed it to ===. but still no luck . Also one thing I notice is The entire page refreshes . I don't even get the alert or any console message . But i can see the alert in chrome

Comment: OK, so no alert on Safari means it is not getting past the value comparison. This is not your problem:location.href = "/thankyou.html";

This is:   if(response == "Success").

On Safari, what value/text is showing up in console when it hits that else statement when the comparison fails?

Comment: @korgrue thats the problem , the whole page is reloading after click .I'm not able to see any console messages which is wierd

Comment: Open up console, open the debugger and drop a breakpoint on this line. else{console.log(response);}

Then run the call. You should be able to check the value assigned to "response" without the page refreshing.

Comment: @karthik006 Are you calling your ajax before a form submit?

Comment: write a console.log(response) before your if(response == "Success"){ condition

Comment: @korgrue . I used breakpoints in the debugger and the page refreshes on the first line of ajax. ($.ajax) . It doesn't go inside in safari

Comment: @nicolascolman . Hi nicholas . I'm not using on submit coz for some reason its not wokring in few devices . Im using onclick of that button to trigger the ajax

Comment: If using Chrome, you can set up snapshots of your values, so it will capture them even after refresh. If you have not done this before, here are the instructions for setting up the capturing.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/watch-variables

Comment: @korgrue . It works perfectly in chrome .My main problem is in Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use a return false at the end of form sumbit to stop the page refresh.